# how to measure the time of selection sort?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

- when i measure the time of selection sort
  with random array size of 10000 in random number range of 1000
  it gives me big time like 14 sec when the size is 1000000 it gives me  1 min i think it supposed to be less than 5 sec
  can you help me with the algorithm to lower the time

```
def selection_sort(selection_random_array):
    for i in range(len(selection_array) - 1):
        minimum_index = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(selection_array)):
            if selection_array[j] < selection_array[minimum_index]:
                minimum_index = j
        selection_array[i], selection_array[minimum_index] = selection_array[minimum_index], selection_array[i]
    return selection_array

print("--------selection_sort----------")
start1 = time.time()
selection_sort(selection_random_array)
end1 = time.time()
print(f"random array: {end1 - start1}")
```

Comment: Is your question "how do I make the sort more efficient" or "how do I time this accurately"?

Comment: Your code doesn't work -- the name of the argument to `selection_sort` is `selection_random_array`, but the body of the function uses `selection_array`. Can you give a minimal working example (including random array generation).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking two questions: how to improve selection sort and how to time it exactly.

The short answer for both is: you can't. If you modify the sorting algorithm it is no longer selection sort. If that's okay, the industry standard is quicksort, so take a look at that algorithm (it's much more complicated, but runs in O(n log n) time instead of selection sort's O(n^2) time.

As for your other question, "how do I time it exactly", you also can't. Computers don't handle only one thing anymore. Your operating system is constantly threading tasks in between each other. There is a 0% chance that your CPU is dedicated entirely to this program while it runs. What does that mean? It means that the time it takes for the program to finish will change each time you run it. Beyond that, the time it takes to call time.time() will need to be taken into account.

Comment: i want for selection and i run with the best CPU what i  want is to lower the time less than 5 sec or less i think the average is this

Comment: You can't, that's what I'm saying. Selection sort is not a *fast* sort. Asymptotic time complexity is not a "I have a good CPU" problem.

Comment: Yes, the OP is asking two different questions, but you have answered neither of them - OP didn't ask how to make selection sort *asymptotically* more efficient, and OP didn't ask how to measure the running time *perfectly* accurately. Of course it *is* possible to write a more efficient implementation of selection sort while still having it be selection sort, and it *is* possible to measure the running time more accurately than the OP's code does.